# NaN to Bool conversion: True or False?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

What part of the C++ spec, or the IEEE float spec, states that a NaN value should convert to `true` as opposed to false?

If I look at the C++ standard section *4.12 Boolean Conversions* it says:

> A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is
>   converted to false; any other value is converted to true.

Now IEEE floats say that NaN compares false to any other value. So whether NaN is true or false depends on how you do your comparision (below). Thus I presume there must be an explicit mention.

```
value == 0 ? false : true
value != 0 ? true : false
```

Now, what about conversion to an integer. The short program below shows that a variable NAN converted to an integer results in the minimum integer, whereas a constant gets converted to 0 (using GCC). This seems odd.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void write( double r, int i, bool b )
{
    std::cout << r << " == " <<  i << " == " << (b ? "True" : "False") << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    double value = NAN;
    write( value, value, value );
    write( NAN, NAN, NAN );
}
```

Output:

```
nan == -2147483648 == True
nan == 0 == True
```

The conversion of a NaN to zero but bool conversion as True seems troubling. I also not that something like MatLab will convert a NaN to 0 using a function like `int16`.

So, what are the specifics of the relevant standards that state how NaN converts to boolean and integer values?

*I'm tagging C as well, since while it may not define the boolean conversion, it probably defines an integral conversion and use in a conditional and I suspect C++ will follow the same rules*

Comment: C says "When any scalar value is converted to _Bool, the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1", but that was added in C99, and C++ came up with the `bool` type earlier, so C++ can't have copied it from C. Not posting this as an answer because as far as C++ goes, it isn't an answer.

Comment: Curiously, the slight wording difference in C may resolve the issue there, since it is explicit about comparing equal to zero. That is, my first form `value == 0 ? false : true`.

Comment: @hvd: `NAN` compares unequal to zero, so `NAN ? a : b` will evaluate `a`, and `if (NAN) a(); else b();` will call `a`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour You're right. In C and C++, `a != b` is always `!(a == b)`. I was thinking of other systems, where both `0 == NaN` and `0 != NaN` are false (similar to how both `0 == NULL` and `0 <> NULL` are unknown in SQL, except that in the NaN case I was thinking of it's actually false as a result)

Comment: Although thinking of what that system might be, I cannot remember at all, nor am I finding anything looking it up...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In both C and C++, the behaviour is undefined when converting `NAN` to an integer type (other than `bool`):

> C99 6.3.1.4/1: When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than `_Bool`, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part cannot be represented by the integer type, **the behavior is undefined**.
>
> C++11 4.9/1: A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. **The behavior is undefined** if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type. [ *Note:* If the destination type is `bool`, see 4.12. *—end note* ]

In both languages, converting `NAN` to `bool` (or `_Bool`) gives `true` (or `1`):

> C99 6.3.1.2/1: When any scalar value is converted to `_Bool`, the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0; otherwise, the result is 1.
>
> C++11 4.12/1: A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`.

`NAN` is not a zero value, and doesn't compare equal to zero.

Comment: But does NaN constitute a value at all?  It's similar to NULL in typical database systems.  I was explicitly taught that NULL is not a value, but the absence of a value.  Unless there's evidence to the contrary, I think we can claim the same about NaN.  As such, I argue that this leaves the behaviour of convert NaN to a bool undefined, unless there's something elsewhere in the spec that covers the issue.

Comment: @stewart: replying to the your objection after two years in case someone else reads your comment. StdC sect 5.2.4.2.2 para 3 (emphasis added): "floating types may be able to contain… **values** that are not floating-point numbers, such as infinities and NaNs"

Comment: @rici I see.  So these statements, taken together, are effectively saying `NaN` converts to boolean as `true`, though this does seem to be an oversight rather than a design decision.

Comment: @stewart: I guess the decision could have gone either way, and after all these years it is difficult to know the nature of the discussion, if indeed there was one. Perhaps today the decision would be to not allow floats to automatically convert to boolean values, forcing the programmer to be explicit about how she wants NaN to be converted, perhaps using islessgreater and/or isunordered.

Comment: @rici The point of my comment is that it is probably not a decision at all, but the lack of a decision.  But I agree that it would be better not to allow automatic conversion of floats to boolean values at all (Java and I think C# take this approach).