# When does NaN not propagate in C++?

Tags: c++, nan

NaN propagates through "most" operations as described in [NaN - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

I would like to know the operations which NaN does NOT propagate. For example, I'm coding in C++ and found that following code prints `1`, which is not NaN.

```
const double result = std::pow(1, std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN());
std::cout << result << std::endl;
```

For `std::pow`function, this behavior is described in [std::pow - cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).

Could you share any other examples?

Comment: Note that the Wikipedia description strongly follows IEEE754, but C++ does not mandate IEEE754. And even implementations which use IEEE754 _format_ for floating-point types might not use IEEE754 _rules_.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example demonstrating functions of NaN which return non-NaN. The list is in IEEE 754-2008, *9.2.1 Special values* (there are some others functions, but they don't seem to be implemented in C++):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const auto nan=std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    const auto inf=std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
    std::cout << std::hypot(nan,inf) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::hypot(inf,nan) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::pow(nan, 0) << '\n';
    std::cout << std::pow(1,nan) << '\n';
}
```

The output is:

```
inf
inf
1
1
```

Answer (score 5):

`std::pow` is not really an operator in the sense that something like the multiplication in `a * b` is an operation. It's a *function*. And functions can have branches which can deal with a `NaN` as they please. Another similar `std` function is, in a sense, `std::is_nan`. This doesn't propagate `NaN` either: it returns a `bool` which is implicitly convertible to a numeric type:

```
std::is_nan(std::is_nan(a))
```

is `false` for any type `a` that allows the expression to compile. Other examples include `std::fpclassify` and `std::isfinite`. I particularly like `std::fpclassify` as an example since it has an `int` return type, so really it's no less of a numeric function than `pow`!

Note that the implicit conversion of `NaN` to `bool` is defined to be <del>`false`</del> `true` according to the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158567/nan-to-bool-conversion-true-or-false), which is important. It allows `!`, `&&`, and `||` to work with an `NaN`. Finally, the *expression separator operator* `,` doesn't propagate `NaN` either, and an `NaN` on the unused branch of a ternary conditional operation is ignored.

Comment: Also conversion to bool: NaN -> false.

Comment: _"it's no less of a numeric function than `pow`"_ Heh, nice try ;)

Comment: "no built-in operators in C++ that don't propagate NaN, with the exception of the ternary conditional operator." Well, `!`, `&&` and `||`. And `,`. Not to mention the relational operators.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Via the implicit converion to `bool` indeed. I've added that. It might be time to wiki this answer. What do you think?

Comment: std::is_nan is a test/classification function, Unlike pow I would never expect it to return NaN.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I don't even know how to wiki an answer. I recall something about "community".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I'll do it now. Now is the time.

Comment: Are you sure that `NaN` -> `bool` yields `false`?  The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158567/nan-to-bool-conversion-true-or-false) compellingly argues otherwise.

Comment: @JoshuaGreen: It's now a wiki answer. Feel free to change at your leisure. (That post suggests you're correct.)

Comment: The function is named `isnan` not `is_nan`

Comment: @AndreasH.: It's a wiki answer - we can all make edits.

Answer (score 5):

The other case I would try is `pow(0, NaN)`. If one has `pow(0,0) == 1` then one should expect

```
 pow(0, NaN) == 1
```

There is a rationale for this, and actually it is needed for consistent behavior.
Even though there is no IEEE standard dictating the behavior of all elementary functions with respect to NaN, there is a very basic rule:

If for all finite point numbers `x` including +inf and -inf (but excluding NaN) we have

```
f(const1, x) == const2
```

then (and only then) one also must return a non-NaN result

```
f(const1, NaN) == const2
```

#Long explanation

This is because NaN represents "undefined" or "any other numeric value from -inf .. inf". Why? Consider the prototypical example 0/0.
If one has the equation

```
 b = a * x
```

and wants to solve for `x`. Clearly the solution is

```
x = b/a
```

Now if `a == b == 0` then the original equation has infinitely many solutions, namely all finite numbers `x`. That's why NaN means "unspecified" and `0/0 == NaN`. Now if an unspecified number (i.e. NaN) enters a function as an argument, it most often will cause an "unspecified" answer. The exception is where the output does not depend on the input, and in this case one should/must not return NaN.

Consider

```
pow(1, a/b)
```

This expression always evaluates to 1 for nonzero `a` and `b`, which makes sense from a mathematical point of view as the `1^x` in a mathematical sense does not depend on `x`. So also numerically one would *require* that for `a = 0` or `b = 0` (and hence `x=NaN`) one also obtains 1.

So if one agrees upon the fact that

```
pow(1,-inf) = pow(1,inf) = 1
```

then one also has to define

```
pow(1,NaN) = 1
```

for consistent behavior. The same applies to `pow(0,c)` but also evaluation of a polynomial of degree zero should generate a non-NaN output on NaN input.

Note: this reasoning can be applied to any function, including the built-in operators.

Comment: @cmaster: Yes, yes. I thought I changed all exp -> pow, but missed the ones at the begin. Thanks.